# Ignore spliting of regex terms?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string which is a combination of `String` and `Regex`. I want to split the given string and store it into an `Array` but don't want to split the regex terms. Regex can occur anywhere in the string. `/` denotes the start and end of the regex pattern.

Examples:

1. `Hello world /[0-9]{4}[ K][a-z]{2}/`
2. `/^[a-z]{5,10}/ meetings`
3. `Start /[A-Z]) ^[0-9]{3}/ prepration`

This is what I have as of now

```
private static final Pattern ignoreSpaceInRegex = 
            Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
public static String[] getEachWord(String givenString) {
    return ignoreSpaceInRegex.split(givenString);
}
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/S7GLgB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Pattern.split()` you can switch the task to use an regex, which finds all words in your string. Therefore you can use this regex:

```
/[^/]+?/|\S+
```

This matches either a regex (assumed it starts and ends with `/`) or a word (no whitespaces). Here is the complete method:

```
private static final Pattern FIND_WORDS_PATTERN =
        Pattern.compile("/[^/]+/|\\S+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);

public static List<String> getEachWord(String givenString) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = FIND_WORDS_PATTERN.matcher(givenString);
    while (m.find()) {
        words.add(m.group());
    }
    return words;
}
```

The results for your example are the following:

1. `Hello world /[0-9]{4}[ K][a-z]{2}/`:

   ```
   ["Hello", "world", "/[0-9]{4}[ K][a-z]{2}/"]
   ```
2. `/^[a-z]{5,10}/ meetings`:

   ```
   ["/^[a-z]{5,10}/", "meetings"]
   ```
3. `Start /[A-Z]) ^[0-9]{3}/ prepration`:

   ```
   ["Start", "/[A-Z]) ^[0-9]{3}/", "prepration"]
   ```